# Building Abstract Syntax Tree

Tags: c, abstract-syntax-tree

I have my parse tree with me, now I have traversed in order on the parse tree and a Symbol table is generated too.
But how do I build the AST for this?

Here is what I have gathered (some unreliable resources):

- In your parse tree you go inOrder I.e
  Take the leftmost child, The parent then, and then the list of other children.
- If you come across anything like SEMICOL, Parenthesis, do not add it to AST, if there is only one child to a node, remove that node, and use child instead.

Is this all I need to do?

Comment: It is impressive your symbol table is generated since you can't know scope at this point.

Comment: @Hogan I have the parse tree, what will stop me from knowing the scope?

Comment: Your system should not have any semantic information at this point.  You have just parsed it.

Comment: @Kraken - how do your parse tree and AST differ? They can be pretty much the same thing. Personally, I've always treated the parse tree as if it was the AST, though I'm no expert - I've only written a few unreleased domain-specific languages. That said, translating from one tree form to another is really just a combination of traversing the old and creating the new - if you can create a parse tree while parsing, you shouldn't have too much trouble generating a new tree while traversing the old one. You even get to choose the traversal order and limits to suit what you're generating.

Comment: @Hogan from my parse tree, after traversing it, i looked at all the declared IDs and added their info to the table.

Comment: @Steve314 - You are right for simple languages.  But then I believe based on the question Kraken is not working on a simple language or is taking a compiler course.

Comment: @Kraken - and how did you "look at" the declared IDs?  If for example you looked for elements in your parse tree that were of the form (var) -> (name), then you were performing lexical analysis and not parsing.

Comment: @Steve314 i have this as the project in my compiler course, here is what the problem statement asks:  The parse tree is fed to the module, all the unnecessary info like semicolon, open brackets etc are removed, the ast contains nodes only that are essential for the semantic analysis phase.

Comment: @Hogan from my grammar i know the productions that will help me declaring the IDs, now whenever i came across the non terminal that corresponds to the non terminal on the LHS of the production rule, i extracted the info related to ID from there itself.

Comment: @Steve314 why would i delay adding the scope info for later and not do it after building the parse tree itself. I know where in the parse tree my ID will lie.

Comment: @Hogan also, is my traversal pattern correct, that is firstly go to the leftmost child, then the parent, then the list of other child, considering my children of a node are maintained as a list.
Thanks.

Comment: I can't answer that without seeing what is contained in the parent and children.

Comment: @Kraken - that comment only existed for about three seconds before I deleted it! You might delay adding scope and other information to the symbol table because it's not obvious from the initial form of the parse tree - or because the parse tree isn't sufficiently built to provide that information yet. For example, LR parsing tends to build the tree bottom-up, so the node for the scope of a declaration may not exist when the declaration itself is recognised - you can't just step up the tree to look because those parts of the tree don't exist yet. Also "after" is delayed relative to "during".

Comment: And here I was thinking that an AST is also called a 'parse tree'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update based on comment

In your example the parse tree might contain a statement node like this

(int) -> (ageArray) -> ([) -> (30) -> (]) -> (;)

The professor expects something like

(intArray) -> (ageArray) -> (30)

I guess.

---

You are making the solution to simple.  It is not simply a matter of traversing your tree and throwing some stuff out. ASTs represent the constructs of the program language.  In order to build an AST you first have to design what the AST is going to look like.

For example, an "IF" node might be designed as having a boolean equation element (this in itself is probably a tree too), a true statement tree and a false statement tree.

You have to design what all the elements are going to look like based on the language you are compiling.  Once you have that design then often a lexer is used on the parse tree to generate the AST.

Comment: yeah my Production for declaration is like 
Declarstmt - > DECLARE listid : type ;

So my parent node will be Declarestmt 
Children List has DECLARE - listid - : -type : ;

Comment: Ah, you didn't say you were using a compiler generator.  In that case, in-order and drop un-needed elements like you said.

Comment: what made you say that i am using compiler generator, well,here is what i did.
Lexial Analysis, using DFA , 
Feed the token stream to parser, now the parser module, will look at the grammar rules, and then from there using FIRST FOLLOW SETS and the LL predictive parsing technique, i built the parser. ( using stack too).
Is that what you call compiler generator?

Comment: Yes, that is what compiler generators do.  When I've done that I don't need another step, the output of the parser is already an AST without any additional junk.

Comment: then the traversal will be in the same order as i asked earlier right? If you can answer it now. :)
Thanks.